# Safe short circuit evaluation in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, short-circuiting, sequence-points

Pre-C++11 we know that short-circuiting and evaluation order are required for operator `&&` because of:

> **1.9.18**
>
> *In the evaluation of the following expressions*
>
> ```
> a && b
> a || b
> a ? b : c
> a , b
> ```
>
> *using the built-in meaning of the operators in these expressions, **there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the first expression** (12).*

But sequence points no longer exist in C++11, so where is the standard part that says:

```
if (ptr && ptr->do_something())
{
}
```

is safe?

Comment: Sequence points don't guarantee short-circuiting anyway. (Obviously `operator ,` can't possibly short circuit.) You still need the actual operator spec to guarantee that.

Answer (score 14):

[expr.log.and]

> The `&&` operator groups left-to-right. The operands are both contextually converted to `bool` (Clause 4).
>   The result is true if both operands are true and false otherwise. Unlike `&`, `&&` guarantees left-to-right
>   evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is false.
>
> The result is a `bool`. If the second expression is evaluated, every value computation and side effect associated
>   with the first expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the
>   second expression.